# Can I skin the Activity Dialog to have a custom animation?

Tags: dialog, distriqt

as explained in the title I would like to know if I can set a custom animation and/or background for the Activity Dialog. I don't find in your documentation any information regarding this... and further than that I have problems setting the Theme... it doesn't matter which theme I set, always see the same.

All this look the same:

DialogTheme.DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT, DialogTheme.MATERIAL_LIGHT, DialogTheme.DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK...

I use the following code:

```
_activityDialog = Dialog.service.create(
                    new ActivityBuilder()
                            .setTheme( new DialogTheme( DialogTheme.DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT))
                            .build()
            );
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to control the animations of native dialogs at this point.

The themes are applicable only to Android and depend on the version of Android you are using.

If you are looking for an enhancement to the ANE feel free to drop an enhancement request into github: (http://github.com/distriqt/ANE-Dialog/issues)

Or add a request to our suggestion site: http://distriqt.uservoice.com